# Register REST API or any other session based API in Fabric8 + connections registry

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, dsl, jbossfuse, fabric8

we are working on few REST interfaces with Fabric8, however taking a different approach in exposing those. E.g. not using CXF, rather doing our own stuff based on netty.

I've been studying the API registry and particularly the examples which are coming with Fabric8 and all of them are of course based on CXF and it is easy to do it that way. However is there a way to register our own RESt API developed on top of camel-netty component?

Same would apply for any other API based on TCP connections only. For example SMPP, where there is persistent session based TCP connection.

Another question would be, is there an easy way to use Zookeepers registry for Connection registry where persistent TCP connections ( or session based ones like SMPP ) can be registered and known to the whole cluster - e.g. their state etc...?

Thanks, Tiho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question got [answered here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fabric8/YmSGnoMGpaE/OBnd9OReFQAJ) on the mailing list